# How can one minimise the percussive strumming sound on acoustic guitar and maximise the notes?

Tags: guitar, strings, picks, strumming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent the noise my guitar pick makes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/624/how-to-prevent-the-noise-my-guitar-pick-makes)

When we are rehearsing with the band it seems that the main thing that one can hear of our singer's acoustic guitar is the sound of his pick hitting the strings. Now he is a strummer by nature and he hits the strings fairly hard, which is certainly the main cause. He thinks he needs a new guitar, but I'm suspecting that it might be possible to use different strings ( but I'm not sure in which direction they would need to be different ) and/or a different type of plectrum to change the sound to favour notes over that clicking sound.

One might think that a simple change of technique would solve the problem, but I have long since given up trying to get him to change ( or for that matter learn ) any technique whatsoever.

Comment: The other question asks in the context of electric guitar, but both answers should be applicable to an acoustic steel-string.

Comment: Yup, that probably covers it. I have no idea at all why the previous question didn't come up when I searched on the topic or created the post...