# Pick Makes Clicking Sound

Tags: picking

When I play my guitar, my pick makes a clicking sound every time it hits the pickguard. I was trying to record a song the other day and the clicking sound is annoying. Am I holding my pick wrong? Is there a technique on how to play to avoid making this clicking sound?

Comment: Welcome to the site! [This related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/624/how-can-i-prevent-the-noise-my-guitar-pick-makes#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=First%2C%20sound%20is%20perceived%20when,Thus%2C%20pick%20sounds%20are%20unavoidable.) may help you, I think...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a clue what guitar you use, but pickguards are at least 1/4" lower than the strings, so you shouldn't be anywhere near with your pick, strumming.

Also, once the strings have been strummed, there's no point in continuing the downstroke - there's nothing else to do except change direction of your hand/arm.

It could be that you have too much pick protruding so it catches on the guard. Or you dig in after strumming the strings. A picture or soundbite might help. A teacher would help even more!